# Logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[400,3] labels_size=[16,3]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a model that predicts the facial expression. The model I used: [link](https://www.kaggle.com/nightfury007/fercustomdataset-3classes).

I adjusted the data so that it has three folders: train, test, validation. Each folder contains three subfolders named: disappointed, interested, neutral.

This is how I ran the code.

```
image_gen=ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=30,
                        width_shift_range=0.1,
                        height_shift_range=0.1,
                        rescale=1/255,
                        shear_range=0.2,
                        zoom_range=0.2,
                        horizontal_flip=True,
                        fill_mode='nearest')

train_image_gen=image_gen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
                                          batch_size=batch_size,
                                          class_mode='categorical') #implemented the same code for test and validation dirs.
```

This is the model itself:

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
 
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
 
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
 
model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(3, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
             optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),
             metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_image_gen,epochs=1,steps_per_epoch= nb_train_samples/16,
                          validation_data=valid_image_gen,validation_steps=nb_valid_samples//16)
```

When I run `model.fit`, it gives me the following error

```
InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[400,3] labels_size=[16,3]
     [[node categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
 (defined at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/backend.py:5009)
]] [Op:__inference_train_function_7946]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits:
In[0] categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits/Reshape:   
In[1] categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits/Reshape_1:

Operation defined at: (most recent call last)
>>>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
>>>     return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
>>> 
>>>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
>>>     exec(code, run_globals)
>>> 
>>>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
>>>     app.launch_new_instance()
>>> 
>>>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 846, in launch_instance
>>>     app.start()
>>> 
>>>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 677, in start
>>>     self.io_loop.start()
```

I have tried a lot of different ways and codes but I keep having the same error.

Answer (score 0):

To get more information about the error, you can run in *eager* mode:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
             optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),
             metrics=['accuracy'], run_eagerly=True)
```

In fact, there was an error with the input shape, which should be `256, 256, 3` in fact.